# I am trying to solve n queens problem using python constraint programming, I get the right answers, however I get many duplicate answers

Tags: python, constraints, combinatorics

How can I change my code so that I only get the right answers without having to remove the duplicate from the list?

In this example, I am doing the 5 queens problem, however, I get 1200 results. There are only 10 solutions for the 5 queens,  I don't really get why each solution gets copied 120 times.

```
from constraint import *


def bad(p1,p2):
    i1,j1 = p1
    i2,j2 = p2
    return abs(i1-i2) != abs(j1-j2) and i1 != i2 and j1 != j2

nqueen = 5

problem = Problem()

queens = range(1,nqueen+1)

problem.addVariables(queens,[(i,j) for i in range(0,nqueen) for j in range(0,nqueen)])

for q1 in queens:
    for q2 in queens:
        if q1 < q2:
            problem.addConstraint(bad, [q1,q2])

solution = problem.getSolutions()
print(len(solution))
```

Here we get the 10 first answers however they are all the same:

```
print(solution[:10])
```

This is just to get a visual representation of a result:

```
sol = solution[100]
new = [["░" for i in range(nqueen)] for j in range(nqueen)]
for val,(col,row) in sol.items():
    new[row][col] = "█"

for i in new:
    for ele in i:
        print(ele,end=" ")
    print()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't understand this "constraint" API to answer, but anyway, 120 is the number of permutations of 5 elements. Think about the meaning of your `p1`, `p2`, `q1`, `q2` and how you can permute them to get the same answer - the answer should be there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you! that's probably where I went wrong somewhere